# Integration of complex function over contour

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory

How can we interpret complex integration over contour measure theoretically?

Is complex integration over contour using arc length measure?

Comment: On every book on complex function theory, you will find that complex integration is related to usual integration. I advise you to look for "Visual Complex Analysis" by T. Needham.

Answer (score 0):

Complex integration is similar to the Riemann integration. Consider divisions points $z_0$, $z_1$, $\ldots$, $z_n$ on the path ( in the order of the path), and intermediate points between them $\xi_0$, $\ldots$, $\xi_{n-1}$. Then take the sum (of complex numbers)

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(\xi_k)\cdot (z_{k+1}-z_k)$$

Now, if the path has a finite length, and the function $f\colon \gamma \to \mathbb{C}$ is continuous, then these sums will converge ( as $\max |z_{k+1} - z_k| \to 0$) to a complex number, the integral
$$\int_\gamma f(z) d z$$

If the path is a segment on the real line, (and $f$ real), you get the usual Riemann integral.

So the integral is using a measure with $complex$ values on $\gamma$ if you wish.

There is some connection with the integral w.r. to the arc-length, in the form of an inequality

$$\left|\int_{\gamma} f(z) dz\right| \le \int_{\gamma} |f(z)|d s$$

Comment: Does this measure has particular name? And continuity for convergence of sum is only necessary right?

Comment: Well, people were trying to find the primitive of $complex$ functions so similarly to the real case, they were integrating ( the inverse of derivatives).  Also, you can integrate anything that depends on a $parameter$ $z$ in a holomoprhic way ( like $\int f(t)/(t-z) d \mu(t)$ and again get something holomorphic in $z$).... the results are more important than the conditions...

Comment: @Meet Patel: Also, if the function $f$ is holomorphic, then you don't need to assume that $\gamma$ has a finite length, since you can use the "antiderivative" of $f$ ( but at the beginning you'd better use just paths $\gamma$ that are piecewise $C^1$. Yeah, don't get lost in the most general conditions, that can be done later

Comment: @Meet Patel: there is the notion of a complex measure ( for instance in Rudin (big) ), so that would be an example. But complex integration just imitates the Riemann integral, and skips the fancy stuff.